# Problems with htaccess htpassword at frontend

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have protected my wp-admin page with a htaccess/htpassword file.

.htaccess:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted area"
AuthUserFile /home/x/d/website/www/wp-admin/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

.htpassword:

```
user1:password1
user2:password2
```

It works.
But today, I published the website online.
And what I now see is frustrating me.
Almost all the pages from the frontend are also asking for username/password!
How is this possible? Wordpress has some kind of link to the backend admin pages?

How is this possible?
Help me please.

Thank you.

Gr,
Ash

Comment: Provide all the contents of htaccess.

Comment: that's all of the content already..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@YFP:

Hey dude, it worked.. I also got another solution provided by a friend. Looks like your solution, but this one was explicitly for Wordpress:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted area"
AuthUserFile /home/x/d/xddesign/www/wp-admin/.htpasswd
require valid-user

<Files admin-ajax.php>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Satisfy any
</Files>
```

Thank you for your help YFP!!
I wanted to upvote your answer but don't have rep enough...

Answer (score 0):

might need to add the activation syntax to a directory/file block - for example:

```
 <Directory "/var/www/html/protected">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Authentication Required"
    AuthUserFile ""
    Require valid-user

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
 </Directory> also dont forget to restart apache... most common issue ;-)
```

Comment: `<Directory>` tag can not be used in `.htaccess`